# Losing SESSION variables in PHP with Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, session-variables

I have an application comprising of PHP files which is for entering a competition my photography club runs.

If I use the features of it thus:

Login page (saves persons id in a SESSION variable)
  Menu page
  Pay fee page -> goes to Paypal -> returns to 'paysuccess' page

the Paysuccess page fails as the SESSION variables are now null
(The session id is the same though, so it's not a new session)

However, if I do:
  Login page (saves persons id in a SESSION variable)
  Menu page
  Some other page (within the app) -> handle data page
  Menu page
  Pay fee page -> goes to Paypal -> returns to 'paysuccess' page

the Paysuccess page now works, as the SESSION variables are still in place.

This system has been in use for a while now but this problem has now appeared. It may be coincidence but I wanted to install Worpress recently (for another use) and that required my site to be moved to a new server on the hosting system, and upgrade PHP from 4.x to 7.x. The hosting people also set things up to use https:
Coincidence? Everything else seems to work fine, once I adapted the MySQL calls.
If also seems suspicious that the problem only occurs when my app jumps over to Paypal and returns. Having said that, why would running some other function before the Paypal jump make any difference?

All the PHP pages do '' straight after the first DOCTYPE line. the person id variable is set in the login page and then just referred to by other pages.

The final thing is that while I've been messing around with it, putting in ECHOs etc to try to debug it, occasionally it seems to work. I might not have been quite as methodical as I should have, so can't say exactly when that is.

Code...... (not sure how mcuh to post as it makes the question very long.

** Login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RO.css">
</head> 

<body>
((snip))
if ($logresult == "Bad") 
    $_SESSION['logok'] = 0;
    echo "Your log-in details were incorrect. Please try again.<br><br>(use the 'Back' button to get back to the login screen)";
    }
else
    {
    $_SESSION['logok'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['authid'] = $authid;
    header("Location: ro-menu.php");    
    }

?>
</div>
```

** payfee.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <?php session_start(); ?>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RO.css">
    </head> 

    <body>
    <?php

    if ($_SESSION['logok'] <> 1)
        {
        echo "<h4>Rushden Open Photographic Exhibition.</h4><br>";
        die("Not logged in.");
        }
    $authid = $_SESSION['authid'];
    ?>  

((snip))
```

** paysuccess.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RO.css">
</head> 

<body>

<?php
function sendtheMail($rr, $mm)
    {
    $to = "";
    $subject = "Rushden Open exhibition";
    $headers = "From: Rushden Open <xxxxxxx@xxxxx.co.uk>\n";
    $headers .= "Bcc:" . $rr;
    mail($to, $subject, $mm, $headers);
    }
?>

<div id="wrapper">

<h2>Rushden Open Photographic Exhibition - 37th year, 2019</h2> 
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "open", "xxxxxx", "Rushden_Open");
if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die("MySQL connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
$sql = "lock tables author WRITE";
if (!$conn->query($sql))
    die("Error locking tables : " .  $conn->error);

# get entrant record 
$sql = "Select * from author where Author_id = " . $authid;
**** - and the above line fails as $authid is null
((snip))
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: You can redirect to the success page with a unique parameter in the query string so you can then use to reference to the correct payment in your DB. You need to design an asynchronous process that is not based on session variables (IMO)

Comment: Ok, I have a solution. Not perhaps very neat but it seems to work. What I did was to make Paypal send back the person id in a $GET variable. 
Strange thing is that if I run other functions the SESSION variable still seems to be present - just that one app that apparently couldn't see it - as if a 'ghost' new session had been started.. perhaps?

From various reading I am getting the feeling that sessions variable are a little unreliable. So, as you suggest Alon, when I have more time I might redesign the app to handle these variables in another way.

Comment: @JohnF Good luck :) If this is an old application then I recommend you to read about implementing the checkout on the website [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/server-integration/#1-set-up-your-client-to-call-your-server) and for the server you have the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) and there are examples there that demonstrate how to create a payment, how the execute a payment and more